# Why did Tim Burton create a similar windmill scene both on Frankenweenie and Sleepy Hollow?

Tags: sleepy-hollow, frankenweenie

I've just watched [*Frankenweenie* (2012)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1142977/). It has a windmill scene towards the end which was very similar to the windmill scene in [*Sleepy Hollow* (1999)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0162661/). I'm not arguing if it was intentional or not because the connection is crystal clear. Did he do it just to reference one of his own movies like many of the [other references](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1142977/trivia) to horror classics? This one was way too long to be just a simple reference. Are there any statements from him or the film crew about it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It may in homage to the classic Universal Frankenstein from 1931 starring Boris Karloff. 
 In the final scene the Monster takes Frankenstien to the local windmill where he is trapped by a mob of villagers. The Monster throws Frankenstein from the mill but he survives. The villagers burn the windmill down with the Monster trapped inside it.

I do not have any direct quotes from Tim Burton confirming this but the similarity is clear.

Comment: Interesting. I watched the classic Frankenstein when I was a kid so I can't remember it in detail anymore. This means that Sleepy Hollow was making references to some classics, too.

Comment: I've just found it on [Vimeo](http://www.dailymotion.com/video/x22c732_frankenstein-1931_shortfilms) and watched the ending which is in essence the same twist as in Sleepy Hollow and Frankenweenie. Thanks.